# Ошибка от facebook "Произошла ошибка при доставке вашего сообщения боту. Повторите попытку позже."

Tags: facebook, facebook-api, бот, facebooksdk

На ранее рабочем боте от Фейсбук после 29 июня при нажатии на кнопки бота выдает диалоговое окно "Произошла ошибка при доставке вашего сообщения боту. Повторите попытку позже." 
Из существующих 5 ботов ошибка только на 2.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете привести подробный текст ошибки?

Comment: @Anamnian ошибка есть только в диалоговом окне. На англиском она звучит так: Action unsuccessful
There was an error while delivering your message to the bot. Please try again later.

Comment: дальше нету запроса на webhook, а в боте установлены нужные разрешения messages, messaging_postbacks

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт.
Скорей всего это баги связаные с обновлениями в API FB.

Решение:

1. Установить новый access token приложения через страничку приложения или по [запросу](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens).
2. Установить [persistent_menu](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/) приложения с новым токеном.